# How do I display user signatures in comments?

Tags: users, 9, comments

Drupal 7 has a "personalization" section on ...admin/config/people/accounts

If this exists in Drupal 9, I'd love to know where it is.
The goal: enable signatures for user accounts.

If it's truly gone in D9, the question then becomes what's the best workaround?

- A custom field in user account: then how to display that in the comment?
- Is there a module I haven't found that does this? I see a signatures module but it appears underdeveloped and lacks the security OK.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Custom field + twig solution:
It is also possible to use a combination of custom field in 'user' and then print in comments.html.twig

[edit to add version that does not use '|raw']

```
{{- content|without('links') -}}  {# suppress links #}
    {# add sig #}
    <div class="usersig">
     {% set usersig = comment.getOwner.YOUR_FIELDNAME.value %}
            {%  if usersig|length == 0 %}
              {% set usersig = ' ' %}
            {%  endif %}
              {% set sigbody = {
                  '#type':   'processed_text',
                  '#text':    usersig,
                  '#format':  comment.getOwner.YOUR_FIELDNAME.format,
                } %}
              {{sigbody}}
    </div>
    {# add previously suppressed links #}
   {{content.links}}
```

[end edit]

Original method (probably not a good idea)...

```
{{ comment.getOwner.INSERT_CUSTOM_FIELDNAME.value|raw }}
```

The "|raw" is for formatted text field (renders the html as html). If your field is plain text omit that.

**The advantage of this approach** is that it is lighter and does not depend on a module that is not ready for production use. Disadvantage: the module appears to offer some more features.

**On the safety of the |raw switch** - One method is to use the Twig Tweak module's check_markup feature. That and other options discussed here: [How to print text (formatted, long) in twig without raw filter?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257171/how-to-print-text-formatted-long-in-twig-without-raw-filter)

Comment: `|raw` is usually unsafe.

Comment: Thanks. Will have to fix that. Would it be unsafe if the field is limited to a trusted role and has limited html for its filter? If so, what's best practice for rendering the field safely? I should note that I got that option from here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/inline-formatter-field/common-twig-patterns#s-images If it's unsafe, perhaps the documentation needs updating?

Comment: Yes, that is probably a bad example. Official docs on the subject are: https://www.drupal.org/docs/security-in-drupal/writing-secure-code-for-drupal

Comment: Found some info on that.  Editing the answer.

Comment: Added method that does not use '|raw' filter.

Comment: Another edit: In my theme, the signature field was printing below the comment links. The fix was to print the content object with links suppressed, then print the links below the signature. This is now included in the code snippet to make the solution more complete.

Answer (score 3):

`git log -Spersonalization` led me to https://www.drupal.org/node/1548204, which leads to https://www.drupal.org/project/signature and https://www.drupal.org/node/2457545. So, this feature was moved to contrib before Drupal 8 launched in 2015 and this functionality is now in [the Signature module](https://www.drupal.org/project/signature).

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but it is the answer. Thanks.