Replacing pattern in Views stripped some HTML tags
Some of my body fields contain embedded code, like iFrame. I use the Views to rewrite the output for a better layout and style. However, the iFrame tag got stripped when replacement patterns were used on Rewrite Results. I also tried the Preserve Certain Tags option under the Strip HTML tags, but it does not work either.
Is this a known issue? Interestingly, the iFrame can render in the Views without resorting to rewrite results.
Here is my sample of rewrite results with replacement patterns. It stripped the iFrame that is contained in the Body field.
<div class="StyleWrapper">
    <div class="StyleTitle">{{ title }}</div>
    <div class="StyleContent">{{ body }}</div>
</div>

Update: I tested this on 7, 8, 9, and 10. This behavior is applied to versions 8+.

If body|raw works then this is ordinary Twig escaping. But the raw filter is intrinsically unsafe. See also (possibly): https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257171/how-to-print-text-formatted-long-in-twig-without-raw-filter

The iFrame also got stripped using body|raw in Views.

Is is stripped or escaped?

They got stripped.

In that case I think thats by default, and by design: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/views/rewrite-the-output-of-a-view-field There is probably some other technique needed here. That's why I'm not posting these as answers. Yet, I think this may be a duplicate of https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257171/how-to-print-text-formatted-long-in-twig-without-raw-filter?noredirect=1&lq=1

I thought the Views strip some HTML tags within the Rewrite Results Text Box rather than affecting those within the replacement pattern. I'm wrong.

Is this bug report the same? https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3425142

See my answer here, same principal.
